# Yaws uses old config file

Tags: yaws

I'm developing a web app on Yaws 1.65 (installed through apt) running on Debian etch on a VPS with UML.  Whenever I do `/etc/init.d/yaws restart` or a `stop/start`, it initializes according to an old version of the config file (/etc/yaws/yaws.conf).

I know this because I changed the docroot from the default to another directory (call it A), then a few weeks later changed it to directory B, and the config file has stayed with B for the last several months.  But then, after a restart, it switches back to A.  If it switched back to the package default, that would be understandable, but it switches to an old customized version instead.

The funny thing is that if I leave it stopped for several minutes, when I start it again, everything switches back to normal (using directory B).  But while it's stopped, if I run ps, I don't see any yaws-related processes (yaws, heart, etc).  This problem has survived several reboots, so it's got to be an old cached copy of the config somewhere, but I have yet to find anything like that.

Any idea what could be going on?

Update:
@Gorgapor - I stopped yaws, renamed the config file and tried to start it again.  It failed to start.  However, I was able to restart a couple of times and this time it didn't switch back to the old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm completely inexperienced with yaws, but I have a troubleshooting suggestion: What happens if you remove the config file completely? If it still starts yaws without a config file, that could be a clear sign that something is being cached.

For what it's worth, with a quick 5 minutes of googling, I found no mention of any caching behavior.